# Save RelativeLayout with content as an image

Tags: android, imageview

I have relativelayout (A template) where it contain textboxes whose content is populated at runtime.On clicking save button,I need to save the template as an image in SD card.Is it possible.

I referred the below link:
[How do I convert a RelativeLayout with an Imageview and TextView to a PNG image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188737/how-do-i-convert-a-relativelayout-with-an-imageview-and-textview-to-a-png-image)
But the image saved cannot be opened.

Is my requiremnet possible.Or else please advice how can I achieve it.

I am behind this for several days.I am new to ANdroid.Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its ok if you just take a screenshot? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136121/android-how-to-take-screenshot-programatically

Comment: Could you please specify your issue. You see the saved image in file manager but can't open it? or you are trying to get access to it programmatically?

Comment: @DmitryArc  Actually I need to push the image to server.(Template image with text).Before that I just try to save it in save card.The bitmap gets saved.But while opening it from its path,no content is shown.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any view or layout to devBitmapFrmViewFnc function and get the bitmap. You can save the bitmap in jpeg using devImjFylFnc.

|==| Dev Bitmap Image from View :

```
Bitmap devBitmapFrmViewFnc(View viewVar)
{
    viewVar.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    viewVar.buildDrawingCache();
    return viewVar.getDrawingCache();
}
```

|==| Create a JPG File from Bitmap :

```
static void devImjFylFnc(String MobUrlVar, Bitmap BitmapVar)
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream FylVar = new FileOutputStream(MobUrlVar);
        BitmapVar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, FylVar);
        FylVar.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ErrVar) { ErrVar.printStackTrace(); }
}
```