# Can a relative view be loaded without displaying it?

Tags: android, android-image

I am trying to save an image with a text.
to do this I was using bitmap and canvas but the saved images were not clear, So  I am trying  this solution

[How do I convert a RelativeLayout with an Imageview and TextView to a PNG image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188737/how-do-i-convert-a-relativelayout-with-an-imageview-and-textview-to-a-png-image)

Now this thing is working fine and image quality is also good but there is one problem

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    TextView textView = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.quote);
     textView.setText("My custom Text adding to Image hare ram");

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    relativeLayout.draw(c);

    new SaveToGalary(bitmap)
```

but now if I try to edit this relative layout this gets reflected on the screen,
is there any way so that I can get a copy of this view 
OR
can I load a layout which is not displayed right now.
for example I will be doing

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.to_save_layout);
    TextView textView = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.quote);
     textView.setText("My custom Text adding to Image hare ram");

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    relativeLayout.draw(c);

    new SaveToGalary(bitmap)
```

here I will be creating  a layout which i will not display but just keep it for saving image. I tried this but this is giving me null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike has given a perfect answer, summing it up we can do

```
public void GenerateImageRelative()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_save_image, null);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.to_save_image_relative);

    Bitmap bitmap = getLayoutRender(view, -1, -1);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    relativeLayout.draw(c);

    new SaveToGalary().insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap,"man","ram");
}

private Bitmap getLayoutRender(View rootView, int width, int height) {

    TextView textView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quote_to_save);
    textView.setText("My custom Text adding to Image hare ram");
    // Here you can call findViewById() on rootView just like usual
    // to get references to Views you want to change.
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int w,h;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
         w =  width < 0 ? display.getWidth():width;
         h =  height < 0 ? display.getHeight() : height;
    } else {
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
         w = width < 0 ?size.x: width;
         h =  height < 0 ?size.y:height;
    }
    rootView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

    rootView.layout(0, 0, rootView.getMeasuredWidth(), rootView.getMeasuredHeight());

    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    rootView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmp = rootView.getDrawingCache();

    return bmp;
}
```

and for saving image to gallery

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class SaveToGalary {

public static final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source, String title, String description) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Uri url = null;
    String stringUrl = null;    /* value to be returned */

    try {
        url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        if (source != null) {
            OutputStream imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
            try {
                source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imageOut);
            } finally {
                imageOut.close();
            }

            long id = ContentUris.parseId(url);
            // Wait until MINI_KIND thumbnail is generated.
            Bitmap miniThumb = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
            // This is for backward compatibility.
            storeThumbnail(cr, miniThumb, id, 50F, 50F, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        } else {
            cr.delete(url, null, null);
            url = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (url != null) {
            cr.delete(url, null, null);
            url = null;
        }
    }

    if (url != null) {
        stringUrl = url.toString();
    }

    return stringUrl;
}

/**
 * A copy of the Android internals StoreThumbnail method, it used with the insertImage to
 * populate the android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage with all the correct
 * meta data. The StoreThumbnail method is private so it must be duplicated here.
 * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media (StoreThumbnail private method)
 */
private static final Bitmap storeThumbnail(
        ContentResolver cr,
        Bitmap source,
        long id,
        float width,
        float height,
        int kind) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // create the matrix to scale it
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    float scaleX = width / source.getWidth();
    float scaleY = height / source.getHeight();

    matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

    Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0,
            source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight(), matrix,
            true
    );

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,kind);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,(int)id);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.HEIGHT,thumb.getHeight());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.WIDTH,thumb.getWidth());

    Uri url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    try {
        OutputStream thumbOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
        thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, thumbOut);
        thumbOut.close();
        return thumb;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}